# How to express the skill of "thinking focused and clearly"?

Tags: expressions

Is there a word to define the skill of "thinking focused and clearly"?

Comment: *Clarity* is fine. Does not need *... of thought* to be included even. *One needs to have clarity, above all.*

Comment: Can you expand what you mean by *clear thinking*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[perspicacity](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perspicacity):

> n. Acuteness of perception, discernment, or understanding.

[AHD]